# Laravel resource create model with id

Tags: php, laravel, resources

I have two models `'a'` and `'b'` and `a->hasMany('b')` and `b->belongsTo('a')`

So when I create one `'b'` this should belongs to exactly one `'a'`.

The problem is with the usual `Route::resource('b', 'bController')` I can just create this `'b'` and don't know to which `'a'` this belongs.

I tried editing the `create()` method in `bController` to `create($id)` but

```
Redirect::action('bController@create', $a->id)
```

Still redirects to `/b/create?2` an gives an error

```
Missing argument 1 for bController::create()
```

---

Maybe a bit easier to unserstand when I use `phone`and `user`.

Every phone belongs to one user.

How can I create a phone? How do I give the `create()` the parameter of the user and still use the `Route::resource`?

Comment: You can create custom route where you pass `user`s id, nested resources like `Route::resource('users.phones', 'someController')`, place it in your form. There are many ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on a wrong direction because `User` and `Phone` are two models and hence a `User` has many `phones` so here `Phone` model is a child model (related) of `User` class and a `Phone` can't exist without a `User` so you only need to create a `User` through the controller and `Phone` will be created when the `User` gets created, for example:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

Now assume that you have tow models as `User` and `Phone` and the `User` model has `phones` method which builds the relationship (`phones = User->hasMany('Phone')`) and the `Phone` model has a `user` method which builds the relationship (`user = Phone->belomgsTo('User')`).

```
// User model
class User extends Eloquent {

    //...
    public function phones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Phone');
    }
}

// Phone model
class Phone extends Eloquent {

    //...
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('user');
    }
}
```

Now to create a `User` the store method will be used like this:

```
// UserController.php
class UserController extends BaseController {

    // Other methods

    // Creates a User
    // URI: /users Method: POST
    public function store()
    {
        // Create a User using User model
        $user = User::create(...);
        if($user) {
            // Initialize/Create a Phone
            $phone = new Phone(array(...));
            if($phone) {
                // Save the Phone and relate with User
                $user->phones()->save($phone);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is the basic idea and the final thing is that, a `Phone` doesn't require a `Controller` to be created, because it's the part of a `User` so when you create a new `User` then create a (or more) `Phone` from the `UserController` after you create a `User` or update a `Phone` when you update a `User`.

So if you want to load a `User` with it's related `Phone` models then you may do it like this:

```
$user = User::with('phones')->find(1);
```

So, when you load a user, you can load all the phones related with that user so during editing of an user; you only need to load a `User` with related `Phone` models and pass that model to the view.

To add a new `Phone` to an existing `User` you need to edit the `User` model so you can load a `User` model with `phones` and pass that `User` model to the view for editing. When new `Phone` being added to the user, you only need to attach that `Phone` with existing `User`, that's it. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I think this leads me in the right direction, thank you!

Comment: Hey, I think I have still some problems. When I use the UserControllers edit method to add phones, where do I check if the user just wanted to change his email for example? And do I still need a PhoneController because want the same functionality like for other resources: create(), store(), show($id), edit($id), update($id), destroy($id) it is exactly like a resource, just the create thing I have to change but when I put all this together in the UserController this will end i a huge mess, doesn't it?

Comment: What I found is this: http://atomicplayboy.net/blog/2013/06/19/nested-resource-controllers-in-laravel/